# How to open device administrators settings in android?

Tags: android

i want to go to `Security->Device administrators` in my settings, however, i                                                                                                                                             could only figure out how to open `Security->`

```
    Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
    dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

how do i do this?

Answer (score 14):

Simply Call:

```html
startActivity(new Intent().setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DeviceAdminSettings")));
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Does anyone know if there any constants for the strings provided on the answer? (Since who answered is not here anymore)

Answer (score 4):

First You have to Declare this

```
    ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample;
```

then

```
mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
```

After this use onClickListner

```
.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
                    mDeviceAdminSample);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                    "You need to activate Device Administrator to perform phonelost tasks!");
            startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ENABLE);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achive it using putting extras `PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT` in intent.

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(
        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);

// put EXTRA from PreferenceActivity
dialogIntent.putExtra(PreferenceActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, mDeviceAdminFragment); 

dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

As Diego said.

> You have to include extras in you intent to specify the fragment to be shown. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT.
>
> You can use for example:
>
> dialogIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, fragmentName);

Comment: EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: mDeviceAdminFragment cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 0):

You have to include *extras* in you intent to specify the fragment to be shown. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT.

You can use for example:

```
dialogIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHOW_FRAGMENT, fragmentName);
```

Comment: please give a snippet