# Dialog box for Device administration permission Android

Tags: java, android

I have a screen lock app like if you tap on it, it will turn off the screen. But it needs to be device administrator which I do manually for it. I want it to show a dialog box when you open the app which will take you to the device administrator settings. Like in the image.[I want to a button in dialog which will take me here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq5Wy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your issue. Check it out and see if it fits.

[How to open device administrators settings in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323658/how-to-open-device-administrators-settings-in-android)

Generally speaking you need to find if there is an exported activity on your device that let's you call an intent to launch that settings page.

Comment: Thank You bro pretty much what I wanted but it takes me to security setting but it want to go directly into device administrator is it possible if is then how :-)

Comment: I see. I'm not sure there is. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html In this link there are all the actions exported from the settings. Perhaps something can help you out